# Creating a list consisting of elements popped from another list (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

Here's my code:

```
txt = '''food: bacon, eggs, toast

drinks: orange juice, coffee'''

groups = txt.split('\n\n')
for group in groups:
    nameslist = group.split(': ').pop(0)

print(groups)
print(nameslist)
```

The output for **print(groups)** is as expected: `['food: bacon, eggs, toast', 'drinks: orange juice, coffee']`

I'm trying to get a list `['food', 'drinks']` as the output for **print(nameslist)**, but Python gives me `'drinks'` as the output, as if it only grabs from the second element rather than iterating.

Comment: You need to start with an empty list and `append()` the popped element to it

Comment: It does iterate, but each time through the loop, `nameslist = ` replaces any previous value.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that `nameslist` is never initialized, and is reset at each iteration, you probably wanted to do:

```
txt = '''food: bacon, eggs, toast

drinks: orange juice, coffee'''

nameslist = [] # initialize namelist
groups = txt.split('\n\n')
for group in groups:
    nameslist.append(group.split(': ').pop(0)) # append instead of overwriting

print(groups)
print(nameslist)  # ['food', 'drinks']
```

Additionally, you can throw away the loop and use a `list comprehension` to achieve that:

```
namelist = [x.split(':')[0] for x in groups]  # ['food', 'drinks']
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you currently have it set up, you are not adding anything to a list. You are simply setting the variable nameslist as the last pop. Try this:

```
nameslist = []  # Define an empty list
groups = txt.split('\n\n')
for group in groups:
    nameslist.append(group.split(': ').pop(0)) #Add popped element to the list
```